# How do I make two consecutive recursive functions execute each level of recursion in alternation?

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-tree

The following is my assignment on a programming course I'm working on:

[image]

Below is the code I've written so far. I've adjusted it to contain the integers in an array, without the need to read them in from another file, to be easily usable by you. Below it I will explain why it does not create the binary tree successfully, followed by my question. Here's the code:

```
/* A program that should use integers in an array to make binary trees
   using the integers, then prints the integers from the tree inorder.
   By John
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NODE
{
    int data;
    struct NODE *left;
    struct NODE *right;
} NODE;

typedef NODE *BTREE;

//allocate memory for the node
BTREE create_node(BTREE t)
{
    t = (BTREE)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    return t;
}
  
//initialize the node
BTREE init_node(int number, BTREE p1, BTREE p2)
{
    BTREE t = NULL;
    t = create_node(t);
    t->data = number;
    if (p1->data <= t->data)
    {
        t->left = p1;
    }
    else if (p1->data > t->data)
    {
        t->right = p1;
    }
    if (p2->data <= t->data)
    {
        t->left = p2;
    }
    else if (p2->data > t->data)
    {
        t->right = p2;
    }
    return t;
}

//create the tree from the integers stored in the array
BTREE create_tree(int num_array[], int i, int size)
{
    if (i >= size)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return (init_node(num_array[i],
                          create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 1, size),
                          create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 2, size)));
    }
}

//printing the integers stored in the trees inorder
void print_inorder(BTREE t)
{
    if (t != NULL)
    {
        print_inorder(t->left);
        printf("%d  :", t->data);
        print_inorder(t->right);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    BTREE t = NULL;
    int data[] = { 9, 11, 4, 5 };   //pointer to integers array
    int i = 0;           //represents indexes of the integers array
    int number = 0;      //number of integers to be read into array
    
    t = create_tree(data, i, number);
    print_inorder(t);
    
    free(t);
        
    return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault, because I have a bad (dangling?) pointer, to my understanding (and please correct me if I'm wrong). When `init_node` which is being returned by the `create_tree` function is finally called, the `i` value being passed to the `init_node` function is == 3 , which refers to the last integer in my `num_array`. Hence, in the `init_node` function, `if(p1 -> data <= t -> data)` is an invalid statement because p1 itself cannot exist, since it would've needed an int that's taken from the `num_array`, but I had already reached the end of the `num_array` before attempting to create p1, hence p1 is a bad / dangling pointer.

My problem is in the return value of the `create_tree` function:

```
BTREE create_tree(int num_array[], int i, int size)
{
    if (i >= size)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return (init_node(num_array[i],
                          create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 1, size),
                          create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 2, size)));
    }
}
```

The point of this:

```
     return (init_node(num_array[i],
                       create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 1, size),
                       create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 2, size)));
```

is to create `NODE p1` and `NODE p2` to be used by the `init_node` function to create a tree, that assigns `p1` to the left pointer and `p2` to the right pointer. `p1` should contain one integer, then `p2` should contain the integer contained at the very next index in the `num_array`. What ended up happening was that when we get to the execution of `create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 1, size)`, it recurses, and with the recursions `i` takes the values `0`, `1`, `3`, then `i` becomes `== 7`, hence `NULL` is returned to the `create_tree` function, and the `i` value passed to `create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 2, size)` is already `== 3`, so the `create_tree` function in this case returns `NULL`, and *then* the `init_node` function starts executing.

What I wanted by the `create_tree` recursions in the returned `init_node` function, was to use the integer at index `i == 0` of the `num_array` in `create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 1, size)`, then use the integer at index `i == 1` in `create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 2, size)`, and for the `init_node` function to be called to create the trees, and then for the alternation between the first and second `create_tree` function calls to continue using `i == 2` and `i == 3` *consecutively*. **How can I fix my code to make it do that?**

(The professor teaching the course actually implemented the code the way I did it, meaning he wrote the `create_tree` function the way I did, except that he used a char array containing chars `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` instead of an int array containing ints, and somehow his program executed properly, and mines does not, which is also very confusing.)

Below is a snippet from my course, showing generally the same logic that I used, used by the professor for his `init_node` and `create_tree` functions. He then runs the compiled program and it works just fine, and I cannot understand how that worked for him.

[image]

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: From everything I see (which admittedly isn't much; that problem and sample are dreadfully lacking on specifics), all of the comparative logic in `init_node` is pointless. The tree order is either specified as per the input sequence or it isn't. If it isn't, than comparison logic per-insert is needed; otherwise it is not. (short version: `init_node` should be a helluvalot smaller if the sequence order dictates the tree layout already)

Comment: Regardless, `free(data)` is absolutely wrong. You **never** `free` something that didn't come from a `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`, or `strdup`, and `data` certainly did not. And the typical right way to obliterate a fully-dynamic binary tree is by post-order enumeration + destruction. `free(t);` only frees the root node; the rest of leaked.

Comment: Your code and, if your claim is to be believed, your professor's code cannot possibly work, because `init_node` has no way to create a node with no children.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. In fact, the call `init_node(9, NULL, NULL)` creates a node with no children.

Comment: @slago No, `init_node(9, NULL, NULL)` dereferences a NULL pointer at line 4 of `init_node` : `if (p1->data <= t->data) ...`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Sorry, I'm referring to the professor's code (shown in the printscreen, at the end of the post). There is no dereferences of `p1` in that code.

Comment: @slago it was edited in after ny comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two key flaws in your sample code.  The first is likely only in the sample and not your original:

```
int data[] = { 9, 11, 4, 5 };   //pointer to integers array
int i = 0;           //represents indexes of the integers array
int number = 0;      //number of integers to be read into array

t = create_tree(data, i, number);
```

The `number` variable needs to be set to the size of the array, so it's zero value will keep the code from doing much.  But the real problem is the `init_node()` function.

In your professor's example, `t->left` and `t-right` are set *unconditionally* to the arguments `p1` and `p2`, which might be `NULL`.  but your code does some *condtional* tests like `if (p1->data ...` when `p1` might be `NULL`.  And similarly for `p2`.  And, it might leave `t->left` and /or `t->right` unintialized.  Let's redo the code, testing the validity of our pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NODE
{
    int data;
    struct NODE *left;
    struct NODE *right;
} NODE;

typedef NODE *BTREE;

BTREE create_node(void)
{
    BTREE t = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if (t == NULL)
    {
        perror("NODE can't be allocated!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return t;
}

BTREE init_node(int number, BTREE p1, BTREE p2)
{
    BTREE t = create_node();
    t->data = number;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;

    if (p1 != NULL)
    {
        if (p1->data <= t->data)
        {
            t->left = p1;
        }
        else
        {
            t->right = p1;
        }
    }
    
    if (p2 != NULL)
    {
        if (p2->data <= t->data)
        {
            t->left = p2;
        }
        else
        {
            t->right = p2;
        }
    }

    return t;
}

BTREE create_tree(int num_array[], unsigned i, size_t size)
{
    if (i >= size)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return init_node(num_array[i], create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 1, size), create_tree(num_array, 2*i + 2, size));
}

void print_inorder(BTREE t)
{
    if (t != NULL)
    {
        printf("(");
        print_inorder(t->left);
        printf(" %d ", t->data);
        print_inorder(t->right);
        printf(")");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    BTREE t = NULL;
    int data[] = { 9, 11, 4, 5 }; // pointer to integers array
    size_t number = sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data); // number of integers to be read into array

    t = create_tree(data, 0, number);
    print_inorder(t);
    printf("\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: cdlane, I just wanted to clarify, the numbers that print out after your explanation are in the order: 4 9 5 11 . This seems to not be inorder though, or is it? if so, could you please explain how this is the printing that has resulted from inorder traversal?

Comment: @John, my printing was to show the tree structure to make sure left and right are correct.  You may need to rework the printing function along your original design to get the order you desire.  Your question was primarily about why your code wouldn't run which is what I was mainly addressing.